# Missing Git command when calling `go get`

Tags: go, package

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.10.2-alpine3.7 AS build
RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ make ca-certificates
RUN apk add git
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/meower

COPY Gopkg.lock Gopkg.toml ./
COPY util util
COPY event event
COPY db db
COPY search search
COPY schema schema
COPY meow-service meow-service
COPY query-service query-service
COPY pusher-service pusher-service

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install ./...

FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /usr/bin
COPY --from=build /go/bin .
```

I added apk add git line.Without this line my docker-compose up produced

```
Step 13/17 : RUN go get -d -v ./...
 ---> Running in d917adba00cd
github.com/lib/pq (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/lib/pq: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
github.com/nats-io/go-nats (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/nats-io/go-nats: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
github.com/gorilla/mux (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/gorilla/mux: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
package github.com/retry: invalid github.com/ import path "github.com/retry"
github.com/segmentio/ksuid (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/segmentio/ksuid: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
github.com/gorilla/websocket (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/gorilla/websocket: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
github.com/olivere/elastic (download)
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/olivere/elastic: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
```

With git line,other problems are still there

```
docker-compose up
Building pusher
Step 1/18 : FROM golang:1.10.2-alpine3.7 AS build
 ---> 44ccce322b34
Step 2/18 : RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ make ca-certificates
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 088fa5ba19a9
Step 3/18 : RUN apk add git
 ---> Running in 01022f57861b
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.70c88391.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.5022a8a2.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  git (missing):
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go get` internally calls the "reference" client-side tool of the particular VCS used to host the package to be fetched. In other words, `go get` by itself does not know how to interact with VCS servers.

So yes, in order to `go get` a package which is hosted by Git, you need the working Git installation providing a callable `git` binary.

As to your second problem, it [does not appear to have anything related to Go](https://www.google.com/search?q=ERROR%3A+unsatisfiable+constraints%3A+git+(missing)), so I suggest you to do a bit of research and then ask a separate question tagged `alpine` if that fails.